# What is the namespace for UploadedFile in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am getting the type or namespace name could not be found error at **UploadedFile** . Please tell me what is the namespace for UploadedFile.

```
 if (RadAsyncUploadAttachmnt.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (UploadedFile file in RadAsyncUploadAttachmnt.UploadedFiles)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                        string strFileName = string.Empty;
                        strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
                        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file.InputStream, file.GetName());
                        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a part of C# built in libraries.

Its a 3rd party <kbd>[Telerik.WebControls](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/radupload.net2-telerik.webcontrols.uploadedfile.html)</kbd> you are using

Answer (score 0):

There is no UploadedFile in C#. That control does not exist - and even if, it would not be "in C#" but "in .NET".